# Why runtime error occur when we try to get the length of the NULL string?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

Why the following code gives an error?

```
 // This a CPP Program 
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
  

// Driver code 
 main() 
{ 
    string s=NULL;
    s.length();
}
```

I know that a runtime error will occur because I am trying to get the length of the null string but I want to know why it is happening?

Comment: There is no such thing as the null string (unless by "null" you mean empty, which you don't). You're trying to initialize a string with a null pointer, which has undefined behaviour.

Comment: My advice is to just use `string s;` The default constructor initializes the string already to an empty one.

Comment: This is not valid C++. You need `int` return type for `main`.

Comment: *"I know that a runtime error will occur..."*  **Undefined behavior** does not require that. *"...because I am trying to get the length of the null string..."* That's is incorrect, the runtime error occurs before then. *"...but I want to know why it is happening?"* Because the program is invalid, because it has **undefined behavior**, because the code passes NULL to the string constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You invoke the following overload of the [`std::string` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (overload 5):

```
basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

And this is the explanation belonging to the constructor (emphasis mine):

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. **The behavior is undefined if** [s, s + Traits::length(s)) is not a valid range **(for example, if s is a null pointer)**.

Thus, you have undefined behavior at work. Referring back to your question, that outrules any further thoughts on "why it is happening", because UB can result in anything. You could wonder why it's specified as UB in the first place - this is because `std::string` shall by design work with C-style, zero-terminated strings (`char*`). However, `NULL` is not one. The empty, zero-terminated C-style string is e.g. `""`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why the following code gives an error?

`main` must be declared to return `int`.

Also, to declare an empty string, make it `string s;` or `string s="";`

This would compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{ 
    std::string s;
    std::cout << s.length() << '\n'; // prints 0
}
```

On a sidenote: Please read [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as the null string unless by "null" you mean empty, which you don't.

Comment: trying being constructive, adding knowledge, will also help those in the future that is looking for an answer.